# Erro a inserir imagem em pasta

Tags: php, upload, sql-insert, image

Estou a inserir uma imagem na Base de Dados. Na base de dados só é guardado o nome da imagem, sendo que a imagem é guardada numa pasta.

```
 $target_dir = "./uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    // if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    //     echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    // } else {
    //     echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    // }
}


move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"./uploads/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);            
$location=$_FILES["image"]["name"];
```

O nome da imagem é bem inserido na base de dados , sendo que só não coloca a imagem na pasta.

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/t-shirt.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\user\functions.php on line 262
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpBB47.tmp' to 'uploads/t-shirt.jpg' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\user\functions.php on line 262

Conseguem-me ajudar?

**EDIT**

Código Formulário :

```
<form action="registo_produtos.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">

<label>Nome Produto : </label>
<input type=text size=70 name="NomeProduto" value="<?php echo $NomeProduto; ?>">
<text class="informacao">( NÃO INTRODUZIR ACENTOS NAS PALAVRAS )</text>
<br>
<label>Preço Produto : </label>
<br>
<input class="preco_produto" id="input" type="number" name="PrecoProduto" onkeypress="return allowOnlyNumbers(event)" value="<?php echo $PrecoProduto; ?>"/>
<text class="informacao">( NÃO INTRODUZIR O SÍMBOLO DO EURO € )</text>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "$PrecoProduto";
    var patt1 = /[^€]/gi; 
    var result = str.match(patt1);
}
</script>
<br>
<label>Imagem Produto : </label>
 
<input type="file" name="image">
<br>
<label>Descrição Produto : </label>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="DescricaoProduto" value="<?php echo $DescricaoProduto; ?>"></textarea>
<br>
<label>Quantidade Produto : </label>
<select  name="QuantidadeProduto" value="<?php echo $QuantidadeProduto; ?>">
  <option selected data-default>- Indique -</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="26">26</option>
  <option value="27">27</option>
  <option value="28">28</option>
  <option value="29">29</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="31">31</option>
  <option value="32">32</option>
  <option value="33">33</option>
  <option value="34">34</option>
  <option value="35">35</option>
  <option value="36">36</option>
  <option value="37">37</option>
  <option value="38">38</option>
  <option value="39">39</option>
  <option value="40">40</option>
  <option value="41">41</option>
  <option value="42">42</option>
  <option value="43">43</option>
  <option value="44">44</option>
  <option value="45">45</option>
  <option value="46">46</option>
  <option value="47">47</option>
  <option value="48">48</option>
  <option value="49">49</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="51">51</option>
  <option value="52">52</option>
  <option value="53">53</option>
  <option value="54">54</option>
  <option value="55">55</option>
  <option value="56">56</option>
  <option value="57">57</option>
  <option value="58">58</option>
  <option value="59">59</option>
  <option value="60">60</option>
  <option value="61">61</option>
  <option value="62">62</option>
  <option value="63">63</option>
  <option value="64">64</option>
  <option value="65">65</option>
  <option value="66">66</option>
  <option value="67">67</option>
  <option value="68">68</option>
  <option value="69">69</option>
  <option value="70">70</option>
  <option value="71">71</option>
  <option value="72">72</option>
  <option value="73">73</option>
  <option value="74">74</option>
  <option value="75">75</option>
  <option value="76">76</option>
  <option value="77">77</option>
  <option value="78">78</option>
  <option value="79">79</option>
  <option value="80">80</option>
  <option value="81">81</option>
  <option value="82">82</option>
  <option value="83">83</option>
  <option value="84">84</option>
  <option value="85">85</option>
  <option value="86">86</option>
  <option value="87">87</option>
  <option value="88">88</option>
  <option value="89">89</option>
  <option value="90">90</option>
  <option value="91">91</option>
  <option value="92">92</option>
  <option value="93">93</option>
  <option value="94">94</option>
  <option value="95">95</option>
  <option value="96">96</option>
  <option value="97">97</option>
  <option value="98">98</option>
  <option value="99">99</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
<br>
<label>Categoria Produto : </label>
<select name="CategoriaProduto" value="<?php echo $CategoriaProduto; ?>">
  <option selected data-default>- Selecione -</option>
  <option value="Roupa Desportiva">Roupa Desportiva</option>
  <option value="Futebol">Futebol</option>
  <option value="Basquetebol">Basquetebol</option>
  <option value="Andebol">Andebol</option>
  <option value="Tenis">Tenis</option>
  <option value="Corfebol">Corfebol</option>
</select>
<br>
<button type="submit" class="btn" name="addproducts_btn">Adicionar Produtos</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Na linha do `move_uploaded_file()`, `"./uploads/" .`era suposto ter um ponto antes do `/uploads`?

Comment: é igual ter ou não , não é daí o problema

Comment: A pasta uploads está no mesmo diretório que o arquivo que faz o upload?

Comment: sim encontra-se na mesma pasta. Sei que estando na mesma página não é necessário o '.' só o coloquei para ver se resolvia

Comment: tente adicionar um basename() na linha do upload basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]) Se bem que acho que não seja isso

Comment: Suspeito que seja permissão... De permissão a pasta de upload para escrita e leitura

Comment: e como se dá essa permissão? o basename() não é

Comment: Antes, tente usar o caminho absoluto, move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."/uploads/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]); ou se não funcionar tente move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"C:/xampp/htdocs/Site/user/uploads/".$FILES['image']['name']); Pois como é windows as vezes da esses problemas

Answer (score -1):

Cara, eu tenho um código para inserir imagens no BD pronto já.
Tá aí caso queira dar uma olhada, eu não tô com tempo agora então não dá pra dar uma olhada no teu código, mas enfim, o meu intuito é ajudar.

```
if(isset($_FILES['imagem'])){
    $endereco = "img/".$id_usu."-foto".substr($_FILES['imagem']['name'], -4);
    $imagem = $id_usu."-foto".substr($_FILES['imagem']['name'], -4);
    $imageArr = array(
        'foto' => $imagem
    );

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], $endereco)){
        DBUpdate('cadastros', $imageArr, " WHERE id = '$id_usu'");
    }
}
```

Comment: isso insere logo a imagem? não coloca numa pasta?

Comment: Com o código apenas para mover para a pasta utilizei esse:     
    if(isset($_FILES['imagem'])){
        $endereco = "img/". $_FILES['imagem']['name'];

 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], $endereco);
}

Comment: Não, ele funciona como o seu sistema, ele só guarda o caminho da imagem no BD. Só que no meu não estou fazendo tantas verificações como o seu código.

Comment: Só por precaução, veja se você colocou um enctype="multipart/form-data" dentro do form que você envia a imagem, sem ele eu não consigo guardar nenhuma imagem também

Comment: Cara, eu peguei seu código e coloquei em uma página de teste e funcionou normalmente

Comment: Dá uma olhada se o problema não está no formulário mesmo

Comment: já coloquei o código do formulário em cima

Comment: Você testou me código para apenas enviar a imagem pro diretório? Deu certo?

Comment: o seu codigo não resolveu, tendo ate deixado de por o nome da imagem na minha base de dados. coisa que já era feita

Comment: Eu peguei seu novo edit com HTML que tu tá usando e deu tudo certo. Deve ser erro de permissão do Windows como o Anderson Henrique disse ou pode ser que tu tenha criado a pasta uploads antes de rodar o código com o nome errado, comigo só dá esse erro quando ou não crio a pasta ou crio com o nome errado, vê aí se tá ok...

Comment: Pode ser problema de Caminho como já foi dito @JoséGomes, faça a alteração que pedi colocando o caminho absoluto por ser windows... estamos aqui para ajudar, mas se não testar oque falamos então não tem sentido

Comment: @AndersonHenrique eu testei com caminho absoluto e também deu erro

Comment: @HigorCardoso o seu código dá erro na inserção do nome na base de dados e não coloca nada na pasta

Comment: Cara, acho melhor tu rodar seu código em outro PC para testa-lo, porque no meu caso, tanto o seu como o meu código está funcionando normalmente. Mas só faz um negócio antes, comenta aqui tanto o diretório exato onde irão ficar as fotos quanto onde está o arquivo PHP que está fazendo o upload da foto.